# kubectl config get-contexts and custom-columns output

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like `kubectl config get-contexts` to show all, or any arbitrary subset, of the columns shown in default output.

Currently, `kubectl config get-contexts` shows `CURRENT NAME CLUSTER AUTHINFO` and `NAMESPACE`. On my terminal, that's a total of 221 columns, with `NAME`, `CLUSTER`, and `AUTHINFO` being identical for all contexts.

`kubectl config get-contexts` documentation shows only one output option: `-o=name`. Attempts to override this with `-o=custom-columns="CURRENT:.metadata.current,NAME:.metadata.name"` (for example) result in an error.

Am I doing something wrong or is the `custom-columns` option that is common to `kubectl get` a missing feature?

**Update:** maintainers decided that there was no clean way of implementing output options; see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1052

Comment: Hello @chb. Could you share the actual error you get when trying to run your modified command?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Sorry for the delayed response. The error I receive is `error: output must be one of '' or 'name': custom-columns=CURRENT:.metadata.current,
NAME:.metadata.name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated by the error message:

```
error: output must be one of '' or 'name'
```

and described in [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-strong-getting-started-strong-):

```
output  o       Output format. One of: name
```

only the value of `name` can be used with the [custom-columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns) option for `kubectl config get-contexts`.

The other option that you have left is to list the current context with:

```
kubectl config current-context
```

Comment: Since I'm more or less asking for confirmation that this is functionality that is not available, I'll accept the answer.